# I took the airlock off for just a couple of seconds, will it ruin my wine?

Tags: wine

My first process was crushing the fruit, putting a lid on it and letting it ferment for 3 weeks. I strained it once, added sugar and put an air lock on. Can it be strained again? What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Your wine should be fine. The alcohol and the acidity should be high enough to kill all the bugs.

Answer (score -3):

You'll be fine.

I could tell you scores of stories of iffy sanitation practices, but have yet to skunk a batch. It does really take a major screw-up to do this (forget to sani the fermenter, leave it opened for many hours/days, etc)

Homebrew how-to manuals place a high emphasis on sanitation, but I am convinced this is because there are a lot of folks out there that need this level of dogmatic enforcement to accept the principle.

Comment: FWIW, skunking is due to exposure to light....nothing else.

Comment: Um, no. Maybe you're thinking of commercial beer that's been allowed to sit in the sun too long. Skunked homebrew comes from incorrect sanitation practices.

Comment: No, skunking is only from exposure to light.  It's caused by exposing hops to certain wavelengths of light, causing mercaptans (the same substance as skunk spray). It can happen to either commercial beers or homebrew.  Leave a homebrew IPA in direct sunlight for a few minutes and you'll see.   Poor sanitation can cause a number of things, but skunking isn't one of them.  If you don't care to believe me, how about John Palmer in How to Brew?

Comment: "Skunky or cat-musk aromas in beer are caused by photochemical reactions of the isomerized hop compounds. The wavelengths of light that cause the skunky smell are the blue wavelengths and the ultraviolet. Brown glass bottles effectively screen out these wavelengths, but green bottles do not. Skunkiness will result in beers if the beer is left in direct sunlight or stored under fluorescent lights as in supermarkets. In beers which use pre-isomerized hop extract and very little flavoring hop additions, the beer will be fairly immune to damage from ultraviolet light. "

Comment: Dr Charlie Bamforth: "Isohumulones break down very quickly and react with trace sulfurs" when hit by natural light. The resulting chemical reaction produces 3-methyl-2-butene-1-thiol, a nasty compound similar to a skunk's spray and detectable by the human palate even when in shockingly minute concentrations. So, it's not the actual temperature or temperature changes, but the exposure to light, that leads to a beer "skunking."

Comment: Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_bottle#Lightstruck_beer